# jupyter kernel disconnects when away from seat

Tags: ssh, ipython, gpu, jupyter-notebook

So I am using GPU server with remote connection through SSH, 'screen' command to keep the jupyter running even when the SSH console window is closed.

By right it should keep running even when I'm away. Nonetheless I'm failing to keep the script running on jupyter when I leave my seat. Some of these scripts require hours and hours to produce end results but I can't have them finished.

Apparently the GPU server has NOT turned off. So I can't think memory is the issue.

Has anyone got a better understanding of this matter and a way to fix it?

Kindly respond. Thank you.